# How to identify a cell as a string or number or both before writing out to csv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, cell-array

I want to write out multiple cell arrays to csvs in Matlab within a loop.
The cell arrays contain both strings and numbers.
My problem is that some of them contain both strings AND numbers sometimes:
For example: Elevation can be recorded as '200' or '200 metres'...which means that I can't specify either a %f or a %s, because in some instances, it will be wrong and write out incorrectly.
Here's what I'm using:

```
 fid = fopen('test.csv', 'w') ;
fprintf(fid, '%s,\t', csvdata{1,1:end}) ;
fprintf(fid,'\n,%f, %f, %f,%f, %f, %s,%s, %f, %f,%s, %f, %s,%s, %f, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s',csvdata{2,:});
fclose all
```

Is there a character that can be used to recognise both strings and numbers? Or is there another way to make the code more flexible, to recogise when the data is not a number as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft your format string by checking the datatypes. In the example below, I take the first row of the output and check whether each element is a character (`ischar`) or not. This yields `0` for non-chars and `1` for chars. I then add `1` to that non-chars become `1` and chars become `2`. I then use that to index into a cell array containing the format specifiers. Finally, I join the format string together with commas using `strjoin`.

```
% Get a 1 for numeric data and 2 for character data
inds = cellfun(@ischar, csvdata(2,:)) + 1;

% Create an array of format specifiers to index into
formats = {'%f', '"%s"'};

% Index into this array of format specifiers (also append a newline like you've shown)
formatparts = {'\n', formats{inds}};

% Join everything together with commas
formatstr = strjoin(formatparts, ',');

% Go ahead and write out the data
fprintf(fid, formatstr, csvdata{2,:});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The first line doesn't seem to work? I know it's missing a bracket, but it's not that. I get this error: 'Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.' Also, when you refer to csvdata{2,1}, does 'inds' get assigned during a loop?i.e. do I need to replace the 1 (j index) with a variable denoting the loop number?

Comment: @new2matlab Oops it was a typo. Should be fixed now

Comment: Thanks @Suever...however, the formatstr is throwing up an error now:  Error using strjoin (line 53)
First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.                                           I think it's because the formatparts is a 1x22 cell within the 1x2 cell 'formatparts'

Comment: @new2matlab Sorry, haven't had enough coffee today yet :) Had another typo in that line.

Comment: ah...the curly braces were needed because it's a cell array..of course! You're a legend! That worked perfectly:) Even without the coffee:) thanks.